# How to show multiple catalog icons on product card in archive woocommerce page

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to show custom icons for each category on the product archive page on woocommerce. If the product placed in the category "For cats" - show cat icon on the product card. If it placed in the "For dogs" category too - show dog icon before the cat icon. And if product placed in "For horses" category - show horse icon too. 
Here is how it must be:

[image: design source]

I solve it with the pseudo element :before

```
.archive .product_cat-for-cat:before {
        content: url('/cat_icon.svg');
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        top: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        z-index: 11;
}
 .archive .product_cat-for-dog:before {
        content: url('/dog_icon.svg');
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        top: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        z-index: 11;
}
 .archive .product_cat-for-horse:before {
        content: url('/horse_icon.svg');
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        top: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        z-index: 11;}
```

but in css :before showes only one element with high priority. How I can solve that problem?

Comment: can you show us the html as well.

Comment: Is it woocommerce?

Comment: @Max yes, woocommerce

Comment: U can use badges. I do not know how to do it only css.